# Managing Azure Backup (MARS) with Powershell - how to add System State

Tags: azure, powershell

my current tasks is to set up an automatic configuration for Microsoft Azure Backup.

What i did so far:
wrote scripts and tasks that copy the Installer to a remote server, execute it, make sure it's installed, register the server with Azure, set up the schedule, the file specs and everything around it.
And it all works.

The problem though: I have now recieved the task to also include "System State" within the backup.

I'm aware, that this is about a 60 second task, if you do it using the Azure Console to schedule the backup. I do however have the requirement to build the script in a way, that not a single finger has  to be moved to complete the whole thing.

Question: Has anyone figured out, if it's possible to activate and include the System State Backups ( which ends up under %MARSDIR%\Scratch\SSBS ) within the OBPolicy using only powershell?

If i activate it with the console and then execute the command "Get-OBPolicy" i find the System State listed along the other filespecs.

However i can't figure out how i would set it, using New-OBFileSpec or anything alike.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: To clarify

Assume i'm in the config window seeing this:

[image: Backup FileSpecs]

I can "check" C: by doing 
"New-OBFileSpec -FileSpec @("C:\")"

What command should i use in PS to "check" System State ?

Edit 2:
Below is the part of the code for this.
How do i add System State to the $inclusions?

```
## Register Server with Azure
$credsfile = ## Path to Vault credential file
Start-OBRegistration -VaultCredentials $credsfile -Confirm:$false
# Create Policy
$newpolicy = New-OBPolicy
$sched = New-OBSchedule -DaysofWeek Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday -TimesofDay 22:00
Set-OBSchedule -Policy $newpolicy -Schedule $sched 
# File Spec
$inclusions = New-OBFileSpec -FileSpec @("E:\")
Add-OBFileSpec -Policy $newpolicy -FileSpec $inclusions
# Retention
$retentionpolicy = New-OBRetentionPolicy -RetentionDays 30
Set-OBRetentionPolicy -Policy $newpolicy -RetentionPolicy $retentionpolicy
## Set the Policy
Set-OBPolicy -Policy $newpolicy -Confirm:$false
# Set Machine Encryption Key
$PassPhrase = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "...." -AsPlainText -Force 
Set-OBMachineSetting -EncryptionPassPhrase $PassPhrase
```

Comment: Not sure ,if this helps  or i understood totally..but check if it helps you ..http://powershell-guru.com/powershell-tip-66-backup-system-state-with-windows-server-2012/

Comment: I saw that too, but i wasn't sure if that's the right thing.I assumed i'd see it with "Get-WBPolicy" then, if it's the same.but nothing shows up there